# Touchpad not working, fresh install

Tags: touchpad

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a completely new laptop (acer). From other threads I've heard that:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

should do the trick in some cases. But in my case I get an error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

xserver-xorg-input-synaptics : Depends: xorg-input-abi-22

                            Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902)

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Does anyone have any idea what would work? A USB connected mouse works just fine.

Comment: Try a newer version first, Ubuntu 16.04.3. If it's still not working, this might be a bug (open a bug report with command `ubuntu-bug linux` in a terminal)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar issue. Did a `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core` and then `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`.